# Android e Stream Java 8

Tags: java, android

Senhores fiz um código simples para filtrar uma lista passando o Id e o objetivo seria retornar um objeto.
Para fazer uso do stream configurei as libs annimon:stream e retrolamba, gostaria de uma critica do código abaixo, uma vez que é meu primeiro contato com estas funções do Java 8

```
return Stream.of(lista)
    .filter( e -> e.getId() == id)
    .map(e -> new Especialidade(e.getId(), e.getNome()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .get(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Se o objetivo é retornar um objeto só, eu trocaria o trecho do collect e o get por:

.findFirst().orElse(null)

E se a lista já for de especialidades, o map é redundante.

Comment: Olá Júlio!  Sim o objetivo é o retorno de um objeto, como estou enviando um id para o filtro então deve voltar um único objeto ou null,  muito obrigado pela resposta.